# maximo valor + 1 con case en sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo hacer una query sql donde seleccione el máximo valor de la columna folio mas uno, teniendo en cuenta que la tabla puede estar vacía la primera vez que se use, tengo la siguiente query pero creo que le falta mas.

la query para obtener el maximo valor + uno es:

```
SELECT MAX(FOLIO)+1 AS FOLIOSIGUIENTE FROM LOTE_ENVIO
```

y la query que tengo es con un case para que cuando el valor sea 0 entonces lo cambie a 1

```
SELECT 
CASE MAX(FOLIO)
 WHEN '0' THEN '1' 
 ELSE '1' 
END 
FROM LOTE_ENVIO
```

se puede hacer en una sola instrucción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias evaluar

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(FOLIO), 0) + 1 AS FOLIOSIGUIENTE FROM LOTE_ENVIO
```

Comment: es lo que necesitaba, gracias!

Comment: [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) también es una opción, en mi opinión mas flexible que ISNULL.